# Brakeman Warning Dynamic Render Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I have code.
`users_controller.rb`

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
    @microposts = @user.microposts.order_micropost.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
```

And view/user/show.html.erb

```
<% provide :title, @user.name %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user-info">
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
      <h3><%= t ".count_microposts", count:  @user.microposts.count %></h3>
      <ol class="microposts">
        <%= render @microposts %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

In  micropost/_micropost.html.erb

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content">
    <%= micropost.content %>
    <%= image_tag micropost.picture.url if micropost.picture? %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    <span class="timeago" title=<%= micropost.created_at %>></span>
  <% if current_user.current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to t(".delete"), micropost, method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: t(".confirm") } %>
  <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

And i brakenman warning Dynamic Render Path, and hightlight `<%= render @microposts %>`.  How can i fix it to pass brakenman ?

This is the exact error:

```
Render path contains parameter value near line 15: render(action => User.find_by(:id => params[:id]).microposts.order_micropost.paginate(:page => params[:page]), {})
```

Comment: You should show the exact error you are getting as text in the body of the question.

Comment: This is exact error `Render path contains parameter value near line 15: render(action => User.find_by(:id => params[:id]).microposts.order_micropost.paginate(:page => params[:page]), {})`

Comment: line 15 is `<%= render @microposts %>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known issue with brakeman, if you just want the code to pass brakeman, you can change `<%= render @microposts %>` to `<%= render partial: 'micropost', :collection => @microposts %>`.

Source: https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/pull/529

Comment: When i type this, Rails raise error: `Missing partial users/_micropost, application/_micropost with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.` . I fix then `<%= render 'microposts/micropost', :collection => @microposts %> have error `undefined local variable or method `micropost'`. Can you help me fix it ?

Comment: @TrầnHồng `_micropost.html.erb` should ideally go inside `view/user` folder as the partials are being used for index view of user.

If there's some particular reason you want it inside `view/micropost`, you'll write it as `<%= render 'micropost/micropost', collection: @microposts %>` or  `<%= render partial: 'micropost/micropost', collection: @microposts %>`. In your fix there's a typo, you're writing `microposts` but your folder name is `micropost`.

Comment: The syntax that worked for me was
```
= render partial: 'review', collection: @reviews
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `partial` and `collection` in my case, I changed from:

```rb
render @attendance
```

to

```rb
render "attendances/attendance", attendance: @attendance
```